# During saving the primary key on the invoice how do I also save the primary key on the foreign key of invoice details?

Tags: laravel, sqlite, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a table for invoices with primary key id and for invoice details with foreign key invoice_id.

During saving the primary key on the invoice how do I also save the primary key on the foreign key of invoice details?

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $validation = $request->validate([
        'user' => 'required',
        'company' => 'required',
        'invoice_month' => 'required',
       ]);
        Invoice::create($validation);
    
        $title = $request->title;
        $quantity = $request->quantity;
        $unit_price = $request->unit_price;
        $sort_order = $request->sort_order;

        $now = Carbon::now();

        for($i=0; $i < count($title); $i++){
            $datasave = [
                'sort_order' => $sort_order[$i],
                'title' => $title[$i],
                'quantity' => $quantity[$i],
                'unit_price' => $unit_price[$i],
                'created' => $now,
                'modified' => $now,
            ];
            DB::table('invoice_details')->insert($datasave);
        }
        return redirect('invoice')->with('flash_message', 'Saved');
    }
```

Models:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Invoice_detail extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'invoice_details';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'quantity', 'unit_price'];

    public function invoice(){
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Invoice::class, 'invoice_id');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Invoice extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'invoices';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['user', 'company', 'invoice_month'];
    
    const UPDATED_AT = 'modified';
    const CREATED_AT = 'created';
    
    public function invoice_detail(){
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Invoice_detail::class);
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/home', function(){
    return view('homepage');

});

//Route::resource('invoice', InvoiceController::class);

Route::get('invoice', [InvoiceController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('search', [InvoiceController::class, 'search']);
Route::resource('/invoic', InvoiceController::class);
```

Comment: To edit a question, click on 'edit' under it. Again: Ask a new question in a new question post. Clarify a posted question via edits, not comments. Don't edit a question in a way that invalidates reasonable posted comments. Delete & flag obsolete comments. [ask] [answer] [Help] Debug questions require a [mre]. [meta] [meta.se] Please stop putting edits & new  questions into answer posts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can has many invoice details and you have written one relationship and you are saving many records.

On the other hand, you can use relationships to save the related data or can do it manually.

Change you relationship first in the invoice model.

```
public function invoice_detail(){
    return $this->hasMany(Invoice_detail::class, 'invoice_id');
}
```

Then in the Invoice_detail also provide invoice_id in the fillable array.

```
protected $fillable = ['title', 'quantity', 'unit_price', 'invoice_id'];
```

Then you can do this to save related data.

```
$invoice = Invoice::create($validation);

$title = $request->title;
$quantity = $request->quantity;
$unit_price = $request->unit_price;
$sort_order = $request->sort_order;

$now = now();

$invoiceDetails = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($title); $i++) {
    $invoiceDetails[] = [
        'sort_order' => $sort_order[$i],
        'title' => $title[$i],
        'quantity' => $quantity[$i],
        'unit_price' => $unit_price[$i],
    ];
}

$invoice->invoice_detail()->createMany($invoiceDetails);
```

Now if you want to fetch the data, you fetch it very easily like below,

```
$invoice = Invoice::with('invoice_detail')->findOrFail($invoice_id);
```

Then in the blade or anywhere for example blade,

```
@foreach($invoice->invoice_detail as $invoice_item)
    {{$invoice_item->unit_price}}
   // all the Invoice_detail model colums
@endforeach
```

And if you want to delete you do onCascade but anyhow lets do in your function.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $invoice = Invoice::findOrFail($id);
    $invoice->invoice_detail()->delete();
    $invoice->delete();
   
    return redirect('invoice')->with('flash_message', 'Deleted');

}
```

Comment: khayam, i created another question on how to update, this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77594848/update-a-table-array-for-loop-in-laravel if you have time, you can help me please