# Update a table array for loop in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I have a table and I want to update it, but theres always a problem everytime i update, it says its null or  request column not found 0, someone can help me? Any idea?

Update controller

```
 public function update(Request $request, string $id)
    {
        

          $invoice = Invoice::find($id);
          $input = $request->all();
          $invoice->update($input);

        $title = $request->title;
        $quantity = $request->quantity;
        $unit_price = $request->unit_price;
        $sort_order = $request->sort_order;

            $invoiceDetails = [];

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($title); $i++) {
                $invoiceDetails[] = [
                    'sort_order' => $sort_order[$i],
                    'title' => $title[$i],
                    'quantity' => $quantity[$i],
                    'unit_price' => $unit_price[$i],
                ];
            }

             

            $invoice = $invoice->invoice_detail()->update($invoiceDetails);

        return redirect('invoice')->with('flash_message', 'Updated');

    }
```

Invoice model

```
class Invoice extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'invoices';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['user', 'company', 'invoice_month'];
    
    const UPDATED_AT = 'modified';
    const CREATED_AT = 'created';
    
    public function invoice_detail(){
        return $this->hasMany(Invoice_detail::class, 'invoice_id');

    }

}
```

Invoice detail model

```
class Invoice_detail extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'invoice_details';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'quantity', 'unit_price', 'invoice_id'];

    const UPDATED_AT = 'modified';
    const CREATED_AT = 'created';
    public function invoice(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Invoice::class);
    }

}
```

route

```
Route::get('invoice', [InvoiceController::class, 'index']);

Route::get('search', [InvoiceController::class, 'search']);

Route::resource('/invoic', InvoiceController::class);
```

[image]

I just want the right code to update in laravel, its in an array, cause my view is a bootstrap table

Comment: Can you point out which line throws the exception exactly and quote the error message?

Comment: $invoice = $invoice->invoice_detail()->update($invoiceDetails); this one the error is SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: 0

Comment: Can you show me the structure of your `invoice_detail` table?

Comment: you can click the link for the image, "database structure" please, i edited on the top

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the right database?

Comment: What should be the right code for that? im connected to the database yes. I tried to edit that but the data is not right, it saves all one numbers

Comment: Have you checked the logs? (https://www.sqlite.org/errlog.html). What is the update that SQLite received and failed to execute?

Comment: its not the sql lite, its the code itself that needs to be corrected. There is a brilliant programmer here his name is Khayam, that idea on the code from the top is from him, its an eloquent relationship. I just dont know what is the proper syntax when its eloquent

Comment: Please check the logs and tell me what the results are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the child records should not be done like this, update your code to this code because you haven't any primary key ID of the child records. so first delete the child records and recreate them with updated records.

```
public function update(Request $request, string $id)
{
    $invoice = Invoice::findOrFail($id);
    $invoice->update($request->all());

    $title = $request->title;
    $quantity = $request->quantity;
    $unit_price = $request->unit_price;
    $sort_order = $request->sort_order;

    $invoiceDetails = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($title); $i++) {
        $invoiceDetails[] = [
            'sort_order' => $sort_order[$i],
            'title' => $title[$i],
            'quantity' => $quantity[$i],
            'unit_price' => $unit_price[$i],
        ];
    }
    $invoice->invoice_detail()->delete();
    $invoice->invoice_detail()->createMany($invoiceDetails);

    return redirect('invoice')->with('flash_message', 'Updated');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Khayam, ive been looking for this, youre brilliant and intelligent. Lots of thanks for helping me. I accepted this answer

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a multidimensional array so your keys are nested therefore considered missing.

Change your code to:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($title); $i++) {
        $invoiceDetails = [
            'sort_order' => $sort_order[$i],
            'title' => $title[$i],
            'quantity' => $quantity[$i],
            'unit_price' => $unit_price[$i],
        ];

        $invoice = $invoice->invoice_detail()->update($invoiceDetails);
    }
```

I am assuming based on your code that the variables you use to assign values to your keys are always present.

Maybe you should also consider some validation upon your request fields.

Comment: i tried that, its not working. It doesnt save any data

Comment: It goes to its original data, nothing is saved

Comment: Does your relation work properly? Is the `invoiceDetails` array having the right values that you are expecting through out the loop? You want to update the same relation inside the loop so basically your invoice_detail relation will get the last values of the loop. Do you actually need a loop for that? The error you were getting was for the reason i mentioned in my answer regarding the laravel update function usage.

Comment: yes it has the proper relationship because i was able to save it, on the save/insert part, the code is  $invoice->invoice_detail()->createMany($invoiceDetails);

Comment: createMany and update are two different things, Their input also is different structured. Debug your `invoicedetails` array and see if it actually holds the values that you want to update.